# R Transition Matrix

Tags: r

I would like to convert a vector into a transitions matrix.
I have a vector t and divided this by its max value to get values between 0 and 1. I then made this into a matrix

```
t <- c(22, 65, 37, 84, 36, 14, 9, 19, 5, 49)
x <- t/max(t)
y <- x%*%t(x)
```

My problem is that I want the columns of the matrix (y) to add up to 1, i.e. to make it into a transition matrix but I'm not sure how to do that. Any suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

`sweep()` is a versatile little function that you can use here to divide each column by its own sum:

```
yy <- sweep(y, MARGIN = 2, STATS = colSums(y), FUN = "/")

## Confirm that the columns of yy all sum to 1
colSums(yy)
##  [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: @ This does make the columns add up to one but it also causes each element of a row to have the same value, i.e.
`         [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]
[1,] 0.06470588 0.06470588 0.06470588 0.06470588 0.06470588
[2,] 0.19117647 0.19117647 0.19117647 0.19117647 0.19117647 `

Is there any way of getting different values for these elements?